# sbt compile 時にエラーが出たら早めに停止するようにしたい

Tags: scala, sbt

sbt のコンソールから compile したときに、エラーがあればなるべく早めに止まって欲しいです。

`~compile` などで継続コンパイルしていると、後ろの方はあまり意味の無いエラーが出ていて、先頭のエラーを確認するまでスクロールしないといけません。

意味の無いエラーとは、例えば変数名を変更したときなど、`object xxxx がない` のようなエラーが出ても無理矢理コンパイルを続けるようで、例えば `func(xxx).method` のようなときに `xxx が見つからない` `func(object) が型が会わない` `any.method というメソッドはない` のようにエラーが続きます。大規模なリファクタリング（パッケージ名を変更するとか）したときに、修正毎にコンパイル→今回のエラーログの先頭を探してスクロール→確認するのはつらいです（IDE使えばいい、というのは無しで……）。

勝手に推測してコンパイルを続けるのをやめる、以外にエラーが10個でコンパイル停止する、エラーログの出力を10件で停止する　とかでも。

Answer (score 1):

> エラーログの出力を10件で停止する

に関しては、sbtの設定で変更可能なはずです。デフォルトが100になっています。ただし、それ変えるだけではおそらく時間的にはやくはならないかもしれません。

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v0.13.11/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L160